# can var change while in loop?(about TCP/IP)

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm curious about TCP/IP(multi threads), one program did change the var and can another program cognize the change of var while in loop?

The reason why I'm curious is I am making a simple game and it has a lobby  to wait for another player to come in, but in the same client. I think there is no way of waiting for another player.

I made `while(ready = 0)` loop and when one client enters the room changing the var(ready) = 1 so I send it to the server, but roommaker client couldn't break the loop....

Here is my code:

```
while(1){
  recv(socket,a,sizeof(a),0);
  ready = atoi(ready);
  if(ready = 1){
    break;
  }
}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Also, when you are testing a variable in an if statement, you should use the comparison operator (==) rather than the assignment operator (=).  For example, your code above should read if (ready == 1).  Otherwise your if statement will always set ready to 1 and always evaluate true, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The question (if I understand it correctly) is asking if, when thread A sets a variable to a new value, if thread B will "see" the variable's value change.

The short answer is "possibly, but you shouldn't depend on it, because having threads share read/write access to a value like that is undefined behavior and it often won't behave the way you want it to".  If you are going to share a variable between threads, you need to either guard access (both read and write) to that value with a mutex, or (in C++) use a std::atomic variable instead of a regular int/bool/etc datatype.

The reason why sharing a plain old variable doesn't work reliably is because computers are very sophisticated now -- the compiler will play a lot of clever tricks to make your program's executable code more efficient, and also modern CPUs will play even more clever tricks at run time to make things faster still.  However, neither the compiler nor the CPU "knows" that your `ready` variable is intended to be shared across threads; in fact they will both assume that it won't be, in order to perform optimizations -- such as caching the value of the variable in a CPU register so that the thread doesn't have to re-read it from RAM every time through the loop.  When that optimization occurs, thread A can change the value of `ready`, but that change may or may not make it out to RAM in a timely manner, and even if it does, thread B may or may not notice the change in RAM (i.e. if it has already cached that value in a register, it won't).

So, the advice is:  don't share a plain variable like that -- it's a race condition and your program likely won't work the way you intended.  For multithreaded programs you have to be very careful to synchronize shared variables, either with mutexes or (in C++) by using std::atomic types (which tell the compiler that the variables are intended to be shared across threads, so that it can take additional steps to make sure the correct things happen when they are read or written).